# javascript var assignment conversion to target type

Tags: javascript

searching for a function, which converts rhs to the type of lhs.
e.g.

```
var x=false // x is boolean now;
x=assign (x, "true"); //should convert "true" to boolean and return that
x=assign (x, 1); // dto, convert 1 to true
x=0 // x is number
x=assign (x, "123"); // should convert "123" to 123;
```

so such a function can be written, thats not the question. But: Is there somewhere a somehow complete implementation of such a thing? I started with something like that:

```
function assign (v, x) {
  if (typeof v==typeof x) {
    return x;
  }
  switch (typeof v) {
    case 'boolean' : {
      return x=='true'?true:false;
    }
    case 'number' : {
      return parseFloat(x);
    }
  }
  return "xxx";
}
var v=true;
var x='true';
var r1=assign (v, x);
console.log (typeof r1+ " "+r1);
v=10;
x="123";
var r1=assign (v, x);
console.log (typeof r1+ " "+r1);
```

which of course is not complete, but maybe shows what I'm goig for.

Comment: You might want to look at [Typecast.js](http://www.typecastjs.org/).

Comment: @pbhd It's hard to answer correctly this question as we do not know exactly what you want. There's only a few primitives in JS, so using your approach you should be able to create a custom function that does what you need, whatever that need is.

Comment: Sorry for being dead for a week... I'm just looking for a function which conserves the lhs type (by passing it as arg so it has the typeinfo). So if the lhs type is number, its mandatory that assign returns a number, and does it's best to convert the passed value (x) into a number.

Answer (score 2):

If you have objects x and y, you can pass y to the constructor of x, and if the constructor of x knows how to convert it, it will. E.g.

```
function y_in_type_of_x(x, y) 
{ 
  return x.constructor(y); 
}
```

If you pass (1, '45') it will pass '45' to Number() you'll get 45. If you pass ('', 1) you'll get '1'. But it might give you some surprising results--the constructor Boolean(), for example, will convert anything other than 0 or false to true. Any string will convert to 'true'--even the string 'false'!

You should probably work out exactly which conversions you need and write them explicitly. I'd imagine it's a very limited subset of all the possible types. (Or re-examine why you are doing this at all, but I hate to be that guy!)

Comment: So that looks somehow what i want to achieve: preserve the x-type. But the default you present is not ok, so I assume I need functions (adopted to the way i need them) which do converty2x, e.g. convertstring2boolean(s) {return s="true"|s="wahr"|s="T"}

Answer (score 2):

There are only three basic primitives you need to worry about typecasting in JS. Booleans, strings, and numbers (because I'm assuming you're doing this to check for equality `===` purposes? Maybe concatenation versus mathematical operations?)

Therefore there's three simple methods to do it:

Convert to a boolean - `!!`

```
var x = 1;
console.log(!!x); //true;
```

Convert to a string - concatenate an empty string

```
var x = 1;
console.log(x+''); //"1"
```

Convert to a number - put a `+` in front of it.

```
var x = "-123";
console.log(+x); //-123
```

Pretty straightforward.